# Launch Matlab not using command line

Tags: applications

I've just installed matlab2017, it works and everything is fine but it isn't in my applications menu. I launched it using the terminal, but there is a way to have it between the applications?
the matlab launcher is `/home/paolo/bin/matlab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing the net I found this solution and now it works:

I launched using terminal

```
 sudo apt install matlab-support
```

and finally  Matlab is into my applications menu

Comment: could you please mark this as answered? Thanks!

Comment: FTI, if this happens to you with other applications that don't have an add-on package like metlab-support, the solution is to create a .desktop file and save it in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: @SeanPatterson I want to mark it as answered, but StackExchange if I click on the V of the answer tells me "To accept your own answer you have to wait 2 days".

Comment: ahhh, I didn't notice how new your original post was. No worries :)

Comment: I put an alarm on my phone to do it in two days from now ;)